# In React Native, how can we share screenshot with a predefined message on facebook or instagram?

Tags: react-native, react-native-share, react-native-view-shot, react-native-fbsdk-next

In react native, im using react-native-share and viewshot package to screenshot. I want to share the screenshot with a message or link but on facebook either i can upload message or add url.I'm able to send image with message on other platform like gmail.  Here is the code.
`const handleCaptureScreenshot = async () => {
try {
const uri = await viewShotRef.current.capture();

```
  const shareOptions = {
    title: 'title',
    message:'this is message',
    url: uri, 
    type: 'image/png',
  };
  await Share.open(shareOptions);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Failed to capture screenshot:', error);
}
```

};

i tried using fbsdk but got an error during installation. The thing i want to achieve is like in pubg mobile there is a share profile option which allows users to share his profile like a link attaching its screenshot